# how to minimize, maximize and close my application?

Tags: java, android

I want to add this feature on my android application.
(minimize, maximize and close whole application)
I know that android version must be higher than 7.
I search the net but I haven't found any solution for it, exactly like below pic:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code for the following functionality.

**1) Minimize Application**

On click of minimize button, you should use below code,

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(i);
```

**2) Close Application**

To close the application, you can use below code snippet. On click event of close button use below code.

```
finishAffinity();
System.exit(0);
```

**3) Maximize Application**
For this functionality, it is kind of little complicated. Because, there are many things under the hood you need concerned. For the sake of guidance, I would say you need to calculate your desire width and height accordingly(that will different for every device and this will be available on the web can be found very easily). After calculating width and height programmatically, you will have to resize the activity with your calculated width and height. Hope this will help you.

Comment: No, this is worng. I want to minimize my application meanwhile I can work with it . by this code , my application close

Comment: minimize means you want to send your application back?

Comment: I want exactly like my picture . i want to make my application screen smaller than before .